# Simplify Propositional Form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I was solving this problem.
Simplify propositional form:
 $$[(p\implies q) \vee (p \implies r)] \implies (q \vee r)$$

I was using this fact for solving:
$$(p \implies q) \equiv (\neg p \vee q)$$

but end up with
$$(p \implies (q \vee r)) \implies (q \vee r)$$

I need help to further simplifying this expression. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT. If looking for a simpler expression:

$$
((p\implies q) \lor (p \implies r)) \implies (q \lor r) \\
 \equiv  \lnot((\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)) \lor (q \lor r) \\
 \equiv  \lnot(\lnot p \lor q \lor r) \lor (q \lor r) \\
 \equiv  ( p \land \lnot (q \lor r)) \lor (q \lor r)\\
 \equiv  ( p \lor q \lor r ) \land (\lnot (q \lor r) \lor (q \lor r)) \\
 \equiv  p \lor q \lor r  
$$

Comment: I think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

$(A \implies B) \equiv \neg A\lor B$

In you expression

$A$ is $(p\implies q) \vee (p \implies r)$ and $B$ is $q \vee r$

Thus the simplification is

$(p\Rightarrow q)\lor (p\Rightarrow r)\Rightarrow q\lor r \equiv \neg ((\neg p\lor q)\lor (\neg p\lor r))\lor (q\lor r)$

which simplifies to

$p\lor q\lor r$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

$$[(p\implies q) \vee (p \implies r)] \implies (q \vee r) \equiv \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\neg [(\neg p \lor q) \vee (\neg p \lor r)] \lor (q \vee r) \equiv \text{ (Association)}$$

$$\neg (\neg p \lor q \vee \neg p \lor r) \lor q \vee r \equiv \text{ (Idempotence)}$$

$$\neg (\neg p \lor q \lor r) \lor q \vee r \equiv \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$(p \land \neg q \land \neg r) \lor q \vee r \equiv \text{ (Reduction)}$$

$$p \lor q \vee r$$

At the end I used:

**Reduction**

$P \land (\neg P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land Q$

$P \lor (\neg P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P \lor Q$